# Multiplying values from textboxes and displaying it in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have two textboxes. I want to multiply the values from the textboxes and display it along with the values from the textboxes in a listbox. Here is my code:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(
    txtItem.Text.PadRight(15) + 
    textBox2.Text.PadRight(10) + 
    txtQnt.Text.PadRight(10) + 
    (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txtQnt.Text)
).ToString());
```

This code is giving me an exception error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

EDIT:
I have another textbox `txtItem`. When I enter a value in `txtItem` textbox, it searches for that item in the database and autofills the `textbox2` with the price of that item. I Enter the quantity in the `txtQnt` myself.

Comment: What are the values of `textBox2.Text` and `txtQnt.Text` exactly? And what is your `CurrentCulture`? They are not valid integers probably.

Comment: Can you please debug your code and tell these values?

Comment: @SonerGönül I have another textbox "txtItem". When i enter a value in "txtItem" textbox, it searches for that Item in the database and autofills the "textbox2" with the price of that item. I Enter the quantity in the "txtQnt" myself.

Answer (score 0):

The strings being passed into `Convert.ToInt32(string input)` are not valid integers.

> FormatException - value does not consist of an optional sign followed by
>   a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

Add a breakpoint and debug to see what the values being passed in are.

Comment: I think this would be better as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @SamTheDev If you read the question, there is no question... It is just a statement of fact. If the poster follows my answer their problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be this helps you solve your problem

```
int a = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));

        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + "+" + textBox2.Text + "=" + a);
```

Comment: Tried this too but its giving the same problem :(

Comment: I have just tried it on button click its working fine for me. You are trying to convert to int and then reconvert to string may be this cause the error try remove to.string. may this helps